# Flask - getting the size of each file in a request?

Tags: python, request, flask

I am having uploads on a site, and using flask as the back-end. The files are all sent in one POST request from the client to the server, and I'm handling them individually by using the `getlist()` method of `request`, and iterating through with a for loop:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    files = request.files.getlist('f[]')
```

Problem is I want to limit the size of EACH file uploaded to 50mb, but I'm assuming `MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH` limits the size of the entire request. Is there a way I can evaluate the size of each individual file in the `request` object and reject that file if it is too large? The user can upload a set number of files, but each one of them needs to be under 50mb.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Set MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH to something reasonable for the total size of all files and then just check the file size for each file before processing.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
       files = request.files.getlist('f[]')
       for f in files:
          if len(f.read()) < (50 * 1024 * 1024):
                # do something
```

Comment: I'll just send you a 10gb file then and cause your server to crash with a memory error..

Answer (score 7):

There are two pieces of information you can use here:

1. Sometimes the Content-Length header is set; parsing ensures that this is accurate for the actual data uploaded. If so, you can get this value from the [`FileStorage.content_length` attribute](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage).
2. The files uploaded are file objects (either temporary files on disk or in-memory file-like objects); just use [`file.seek()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) and [`file.tell()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) on these to determine their size without having to read the whole object. It *may* be that an in-memory file object doesn't support seeking, at which point you should be able to read the whole file into memory as it'll be small enough not to need a temporary on-disk file.

Combined, the best way to test for individual file sizes then is:

```
def get_size(fobj):
    if fobj.content_length:
        return fobj.content_length

    try:
        pos = fobj.tell()
        fobj.seek(0, 2)  #seek to end
        size = fobj.tell()
        fobj.seek(pos)  # back to original position
        return size
    except (AttributeError, IOError):
        pass

    # in-memory file object that doesn't support seeking or tell
    return 0  #assume small enough
```

then in your loop:

```
for fobj in request.files.getlist('f[]'):
    if get_size(fobj) > 50 * (1024 ** 2):
        abort(413)  # request entity too large
```

This avoids having to read data into memory altogether.